# Selenium remote using Cloud Run Service terrible slow and crashing session

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, google-cloud-run, selenium-remotedriver

I'm quite new to docker and I'm trying to create a scraper using `Selenium Remote` and `Cloud Run Services` based on [this](https://www.roelpeters.be/how-to-deploy-a-scraping-script-and-selenium-in-google-cloud-run/) site.

I mainly have three problems (for now):

1. The scraper is WAY slower, compared to running it locally. Is this normal? Is remote selenium way slower or I'm doing something wrong?
2. I frequently find an error related to session timeout. How can I increase the session timeout?
3. Everytime the script crashes, then I get this error:

   `selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message:`

   `401 Unauthorized`

   `Your client does not have permission to the requested URL /wd/hub/session`

Or that the session of ID xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx does not exists, when it shouldn't actually exists because it previosly crashed. Why I'm facing this errors and how can I solve this?

I can post my code if needed, but even with getting `example.com` with the browser I face this problems.